# XML to SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, xml

We have following XML data structure from which we would like to insert new data and update existing data in a SQL Server table.

Tables are `SALES_HEADER` and `SALES_DETAILS`.

`SALES_HEADER` columns

```
ID (PK)
INV_NO
DATE
CUST_ID (FK FROM CUSTOMER MASTER)
```

`SALES_DETAILS` columns:

```
ID (PK)
HEADER_ID (FK FROM SALES_HEADER)
STK_ID (FK FROM STK MASTER)
QTY
RATE
AMT
```

My XML is as under

```
<SALESDATA>
<SALESHEADER>
    <BILLNO>1</BILLNO>
    <DATE>01/08/2015</DATE>
    <CUSTOMERCODE>54</CUSTOMERCODE>
        <SALESDETAILS>
            <STK_ID>5</STK_ID>
            <QTY>10</QTY>
            <RATE>12</RATE>
            <AMOUNT>120<AMOUNT>
        </SALESDETAILS>
        <SALESDETAILS>
            <STK_ID>7</STK_ID>
            <QTY>9</QTY>
            <RATE>54</RATE>
            <AMOUNT>486<AMOUNT>
        </SALESDETAILS>
        <SALESDETAILS>
            <STK_ID>78</STK_ID>
            <QTY>62</QTY>
            <RATE>18</RATE>
            <AMOUNT>1116<AMOUNT>
        </SALESDETAILS>
</SALESHEADER>
```

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to know the **data types** of your columns, and whether or not the `ID` columns are `IDENTITY` or not ...

Comment: ID is int
INV_NO = numeric(9, 0)
DATE = date
CUST_ID = int

SALES_DETAILS columns:

ID = int
HEADER_ID = int
STK_ID  =int
QTY = numeric(18, 0)
RATE = numeric(18, 0)
AMT = decimal(18, 0)

Comment: xml is xml file name H:\SDATA.XML

Comment: And is `ID` an `IDENTITY` column or not??

Comment: yes id is and IDENTITY Column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not making it very easy for us to **help you** by obviously *not* mentioning a lot of crucial details about your task!

I tried to do something - at least to insert the header information into the table (or updating it, if it already exists).

Take this is a learning guide - and extend it to also cover the `SALES_DETAILS` table, which I **REALLY** do not know how to handle since you're not telling us some many things about your setup....... learn from my sample and do the second step yourself, as a learning experience!

```
-- Load XML from file
DECLARE @XmlContent XML 

SELECT @XmlContent = CAST(BulkColumn AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'H:\SDATA.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS e;

SELECT @XmlContent

-- declare a temp table (or table variable) to hold the data
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (BillNo NUMERIC(9, 0), SalesDate DATE, CustomerID INT, DetailsXML XML)

-- insert header data and the details XML into temporary table
INSERT INTO @TempTable (BillNo, SalesDate, CustomerID, DetailsXML)
    SELECT
        BillNo = XCHDR.value('(BILLNO)[1]', 'numeric(9,0)'),
        SalesDate = XCHDR.value('(DATE)[1]', 'date'),
        CustomerID = XCHDR.value('(CUSTOMERCODE)[1]', 'int'),
        DetailsXml = XCHDR.query('SALESDETAILS')
    FROM
        @XmlContent.nodes('/SALESDATA/SALESHEADER') XTHDR(XCHDR)

SELECT * FROM @TempTable

-- update those rows that already exist in the SALES_HEADER table
UPDATE 
    INV_NO = tt.BillNo,
    [Date] = tt.SalesDate,
    [CUST_ID] = tt.CustomerID
FROM dbo.SALES_HEADER hdr
INNER JOIN @TempTable tt ON tt.BillNo = hdr.INV_NO

-- insert those rows that don't exist yet - record the newly inserted ID values
INSERT INTO dbo.SALES_HEADER (INV_NO, [Date], CUST_ID)
    SELECT tt.BillNo, tt.SalesDate, tt.CustomerID 
    FROM @TempTable tt
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.SALES_HEADER hdr WHERE hdr.INV_NO = tt.BillNo)
```

Comment: how to mention the file name in this?

Comment: AND IN SINGLE QUERY WANT TO INSERT IF NEW RECORD AND UPDATE IF EXISTING RECORD

Comment: I am very new to this, i dont know how to link path and file name to @xmlcontect and what if i want to update the existing data if invoice number is already exists

Comment: file may contain 5000 to 6000 Invoice records

Comment: error Must declare the scalar variable "@XmlContent".